# VB.NET Error Rows cannot be programmaticaly added

Tags: database, vb.net, stored-procedures

I would like to retrieve the Car Authorizations information that are going to expire after 3 days from the database and show them in a datagrid in the form load. This is the code that I implement in VB.NET

```
Dim ConnectString As String
ConnectString = ""
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectString)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = connection
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "AuthorizationExp"

Try
    connection.Open()

    Dim dreader As SqlDataReader
    dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While (dreader.Read())
        Dim n As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = (dreader("AuthorizationNo").ToString)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = (dreader("DriverID").ToString)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(2).Value = (dreader("PlateNo").ToString)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(3).Value = (dreader("AuthorizationStart").ToString)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(4).Value = (dreader("AuthorizationEnd").ToString)
    End While
    dreader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred (" + ex.Message + ")")
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

I retrieve them from a stored procedure:

```
create procedure AuthorizationExp
as
select  CarDriver.AuthorizationNo, CarDriver.DriverID, CarDriver.PlateNo, CarDriver.AuthorizationStart, CarDriver.AuthorizationEnd
from CarDriver 
where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), AuthorizationEnd) <=3
```

The error that I got is

```
Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound
```

Any help guys
Thanks

Comment: You cannot add row in datagrid with databound .. insert record to the datasource ..

Comment: If you're not loading the data directly to the datagridview, you could try not binding it all.  Or make your own table bind it to the datagridview and load the table with the data.  You can add the row to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually initially load your data into a `DataTable` and then bind that to the `DataGridView` using the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) method on the `DataTable` and then setting that to the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) property on the `DataGridView`.

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

table.Load(reader)
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```